# Getting view Null in fragment when onPageSelected() of ViewPager called Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

**Using Kotlin Android Extensions for views initialization**

Activity Code for PageSelected:

```
introPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                when(position) {
                    0 -> (pagerAdapter.getItem(position) as SearchFragment).startViewAnimations()
                }
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }
        })
```

Fragment Method:

```
fun startViewAnimations() {
        rippleBack?.startRippleAnimation()
        centerImage?.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate_indefinitely))

        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({
            relAllViews?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            relAllViews?.animate()?.alpha(1.0f)
            rippleBack?.animate()?.alpha(0.0f)
            rippleBack?.visibility = View.GONE
            rippleBack?.stopRippleAnimation()
            centerImage?.clearAnimation()
        }, 3500)
    }
```

If I use the same function in the Fragment's `onViewCreated()` it works fine code sample:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        startViewAnimations()
    }
```

Full Fragment Code:

```
package com.beeland.consumer.fragment.appintro

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import com.beeland.consumer.R
import com.beeland.consumer.utils.Utils
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_search.*

/**
 * @author Yash
 * @since 23-04-2018.
 */
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    /**
     * Method to replace layouts in App Intro Section
     *
     * @return IntroFragment's new instance
     */
    fun newInstance(): SearchFragment {
        val intro = SearchFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString("", "")
        intro.arguments = args
        return intro
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        startViewAnimations()
    }

    fun startViewAnimations() {
        rippleBack?.startRippleAnimation()
        centerImage?.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate_indefinitely))

        val handler = Handler()
        handler.postDelayed({
            relAllViews?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            relAllViews?.animate()?.alpha(1.0f)
            rippleBack?.animate()?.alpha(0.0f)
            rippleBack?.visibility = View.GONE
            rippleBack?.stopRippleAnimation()
            centerImage?.clearAnimation()

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(txt5Km)
            }, 300)

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(txtPostalDelivery)
            }, 600)

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(img1)
            }, 900)

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(img2)
            }, 1200)

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(img3)
            }, 1500)

            handler.postDelayed({
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(imgRes1)
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(imgRes2)
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(imgRes3)
                Utils.bounceAnimationVisible(imgRes4)
            }, 1800)

        }, 3500)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @DEADMC I am getting the views null when i call the 'startViewAnimations()' from the Activity

Comment: where are rippleBack and other views are placed, I mean how do you inflate them?

Comment: override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
    }

Comment: @DEADMC for inflating views
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_search.*

Answer (score 0):

View pager by default caches only 3 fragments. Current, previous and next.

When you move to some page all pages which are out of this range call `onDestroyView()` and the view is destroyed i.e. it becomes null. When  this page gets into the range again it must create the view again thus calling `onCreateView()`. The view is null while the it is creating

Range in which fragments (actually views) will are cached can be customized with `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)`.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried changing the the OffScreenPageLimit but no luck :(
Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @YashParikh How much fragments are in your adapter? And are you using FragmentStatePagerAdpater or FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: Using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and there are total 4 fragments

Comment: @YashParikh Does it crash every time you move to a different fragment?

Comment: No when i get back on particular fragment i.e position 0

Comment: @YashParikh Wait it happens when you get back on fragment on which you've been before?

Comment: Yes app is getting crashed

Comment: Nope i haven't added any :(

Comment: I have edited question and added the full fragment Code

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help.. issue has been resolved, it was the problem in my ViewPager Adapter, i was always creating the new instance for the fragment so the Views were getting destroyed and found null... :)